# How to Split Data for Multiple Slides in Next.js App Using Swiper?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

How can I split the "data" array into two or more slides when using Swiper to display a product grid in my Next.js app? For instance, suppose I have the following "data" array: [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6], and I would like to have "item1", "item2", and "item3" in the first slide, and the rest in the second slide. How can I achieve this?